# PHP How to comparearrays and activatie function

Tags: php, arrays, function, sms, response

Ok, I am trying to create a somewhat dynamic sms auto-responder with PHP.  Right now, I have a basic one up and running which can respond to single word inputs.  See here:

```
<?php

/* Include twilio-php, the official Twilio PHP Helper Library,
 * which can be found at
 * http://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries
*/

include('Services/Twilio.php');

/* Controller: Match the keyword with the customized SMS reply. */
function index(){
    $response = new Services_Twilio_Twiml();
    $response->sms("Reply with one of the following keywords:
monkey, dog, pigeon, owl.");
    echo $response;
  }

function monkey(){
    $response = new Services_Twilio_Twiml();
    $response->sms("Monkey. A small to medium-sized primate that
typically has a long tail, most kinds of which live in trees in
tropical countries.");
    echo $response;
}

function dog(){
    $response = new Services_Twilio_Twiml();
    $response->sms("Dog. A domesticated carnivorous mammal that
typically has a long snout, an acute sense of smell, and a barking,
howling, or whining voice.");
    echo $response;
}

function pigeon(){
    $response = new Services_Twilio_Twiml();
    $response->sms("Pigeon. A stout seed- or fruit-eating bird with
a small head, short legs, and a cooing voice, typically having gray and
white plumage.");
    echo $response;
}

function owl(){
    $response = new Services_Twilio_Twiml();
    $response->sms("Owl. A nocturnal bird of prey with large
forward-facing eyes surrounded by facial disks, a hooked beak,
and typically a loud call.");
    echo $response;
}

/* Read the contents of the 'Body' field of the Request. */
$body = $_REQUEST['Body'];

/* Remove formatting from $body until it is just lowercase
 characters without punctuation or spaces. */
$result = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/u", " ", $body);
$result = trim($result);
$result = strtolower($result);

/* Router: Match the ‘Body’ field with index of keywords */
switch ($result) {
   case 'monkey':
        monkey();
        break;
    case 'dog':
        dog();
        break;
    case 'pigeon':
        pigeon();
        break;
    case 'owl':
        owl();
        break;

/* Optional: Add new routing logic above this line. */
    default:
        index();
}
```

What I am trying to accomplish is to get this to respond if someone texts in something like "Hey, is that dog for sale?".  As of right now, it only works if the word 'Dog' or 'dog' is texted.

I've been messing with arrays, preg_match, stripos/ strpos, but cannot for the life of me make it function correctly.  Can anyone help with at least pointing me in the right direction?  I'm in the process of learning to code to fix my own problem because there were none available, so bear with me that I'm new at this.

Here's what I have right now, which still doesn't work but I feel like is the right direction.  This is just a replacement of the bottom of the code section :

```
/* Read the contents of the 'Body' field of the Request. */
 $body = $_REQUEST['Body'];

 /* Remove formatting from $body until it is just lowercase
characters without punctuation or spaces. */
 $result = rtrim($body, ", . ! ?");
 $result = strtolower($result);
 $result = explode(' ', $result);
 $keyword = array('dog', 'pigeon', 'owl', 'monkey');
 $testword = array_intersect($result, $keyword);
 print($testword);


/* Router: Match the ‘Body’ field with index of keywords */
switch ($testword) {
    case 'monkey':
        monkey();
        break;
    case 'dog':
        dog();
        break;
    case 'pigeon':
        pigeon();
        break;
    case 'owl':
        owl();
        break;

/* Optional: Add new routing logic above this line. */
    default:
    index();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

array_intersect returns an array, it seems that you take "testword" as a string. Maybe you can try in_array to check which keyword it exactly matches

Comment: Ok, so using the 'in_array' function, how would I do the following?:

PHP app needs to check for the keywords 'owl, pigeon, monkey, dog' in strings such as "what does that dog cost?" or 'What can you tell me about the monkey in that cage?", and if a keyword match is found, run a function based on the keyword.